# How to detect if an ellipse collides with an another ellipse / rectangle

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, ellipse

I want to detect if ellipse collides with another ellipse and rectangle. How I can do it?

I'm writing in C++. I want to use it for a game.

Comment: Is this for a game? It's important :)

Comment: What is an ellipse for you? Just the perimeter or the area inside too?

Comment: Rasterized ellipse, as in displayed in pixels, or actual geometrical ellipse?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is for a game, then exactness should not be an issue. 
Treat your ellipse as a polygon, that is, choose N evenly distributed points on your ellipse and treat is as a polygon. Adjuct N to the level of the desired correctness.

Now you need to test if a convex polygon collides with a rectangle. And the latter is a convex polygon as well. Here's a link for [convex polygon collision detection](http://www.gpwiki.org/index.php/Polygon_Collision)

Answer (score 1):

If you need precise answer, than you have to describe your figures as functions and use [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) for finding intersection points